# Replicator equation for mixed strategies?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, game-theory

The the replicator equation is usually defined for pure strategies. More specifically, the replicator eqn for $n$ strategies is given by:
\begin{equation}
  \dot x_{i} = x_{i} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j} - \phi \right)
  \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the frequency of the strategy $i$, $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the payoff matrix, and $\phi$ is the average fitness of the population.

**Question:** Does anyone know of a formulation of the replicator eqn for **mixed** strategies?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but since you are considering restriction of system to standard simplex, doesn't vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ represent a mixed strategy?

Comment: @Evgeny I believe the simplex formed by the vectors $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ represent the frequencies of different pure strategies. For instance, in the case of the Hawk-Dove game, $x_1$ could be the frequency of Hawks and $x_2$ the frequency of Doves.

Comment: Well, I was told that assigning frequency or probability to choice of each strategy is exactly what mixed strategy is...

Comment: @Evgeny My understanding is that, in the replicator eqn, $x_i$ refers to the frequency of individuals playing a pure strategy $i$ (e.g., 3/4 of the population play Hawk and only Hawk). In order to have a mixed strategy, the same individual would play different pure strategies at different frequencies (e.g., the same individual plays Hawk 3/4 of the time).